# separating a multi-page ascii file

Tags: bash, shell, split

I have a multi-page ascii file, and I need to be able to separate this file into single page ascii files.

At the end of each page should be a page break inserted. My original thoughts are to read up to a page break, output to file, but then how would I make it read to a page break and then continue to start over reading from that page break to the next? Or is there another, easier way of doing this?

Comment: In the original file, how do you distinguish between one page and the next?

Comment: I don't have the means of checking the file itself to see what the hex chars are, but I believe it's a form feed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csplit` allows you to split a file by regex.

Comment: looking at a regexp list of special chars, I don't see one for a page break... is there one?

Comment: You can always specify the character itself. FF is U+000C.

Comment: This answer is correct for what I was asking. After some additional digging, discovered that the format used multiple carriage returns as opposed to a form feed/page break to separate the pages (... dumb). Luckily the file is formatted for 67 lines per page, so I was able to use `split` on a page count.  We unfortunately cannot change the output formatting of these files or else I would =(